# Google Vision API problem with batch annotations

Tags: python, batch-processing, google-cloud-vision

I wanted to use Cloud Vision API to detect labels from ca. 40K photographs and download the results as CSV files. I uploaded photos into the cloud storage and used the following code, but the error occured. I asked a person who uses python in his job but he cannot deal with this error. Can you help mi with fixing it?

```
TypeError: Invalid constructor input for BatchAnnotateImagesRequest: [{'image': source {
  image_uri: "gs://bucket/image-path.jpg"
}
, 'features': [{'type': <Type.LABEL_DETECTION: 4>}]}]
```

The code I used:

```
from google.cloud import
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import ImageAnnotatorClient
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types
import os
import json
import numpy as np
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='C://file-path.json'

#(created in step 1)
# Get GCS bucket
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket_name')
image_paths = []
for blob in list(bucket.list_blobs()):
    image_paths.append("gs://bucket_name/"+blob.name)

# We can send a maximum of 16 images per request.
start = 0
end = 16
label_output = []
for i in range(int(np.floor(len(image_paths)/16))+1):
    requests = []
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    for image_path in image_paths[start:end]:
        image = types.Image()
        image.source.image_uri = image_path
        requests.append({'image': image,'features': [{'type': vision.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}]})
        response = client.batch_annotate_images(requests)
    for image_path, i in zip(image_paths[start:end], response.responses):
        labels = [{label.description: label.score} for label in i.label_annotations]
        labels = {k: v for d in labels for k, v in d.items()}
        filename = os.path.basename(image_path)
        l = {'filename': filename, 'labels': labels}
        label_output.append(l)
    start = start+16
    end = end+16
#export results to CSV file
for l in label_output:
    print('"' + label_output[l]['filename'] + '";', end = '')
    for label in label_output[l]["labels"]:
        print('"' + label + '";"' + label_output[l][label] + '";', end = '')
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

`batch_annotate_images()` is not getting the contents of `requests` properly. To fix this, just assign your variable `requests` explicitly to the parameter `requests` of `batch_annotate_images()`.

```
response = client.batch_annotate_images(requests=requests)
```

See [batch_annotate_images()](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/image_annotator.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.services.image_annotator.ImageAnnotatorClient.batch_annotate_images) for reference. Also if you are planning to update your Vision API to 2.3.1, you might encounter errors on `features:` see this [reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/vision_v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Feature) for the updated usage of its parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but after improving the code the other error occured:

  `File "C:\Users\tgrzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 588, in _GetFieldByName
    return message_descriptor.fields_by_name[field_name]
KeyError: 'type'`

Comment: @geotomaszke can you edit your post to include the whole error message? It is quite difficult to figure out which line encountered this error.